Java Jersey Client to Server Multipart POST Request Results in HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
I'm working with two Java containers where the first container (Client) sends a list of images to a service exposed by the second container (Server) using a multipart POST request. However, the server always responds with a 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error.
Here is the code for the client:
public class ClientController {
    
    public List<...> doRequest(List<InputStream> images, Integer value1, double value2) {
        try (MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()) {

            Client client = ClientBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                .build();
            
            WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI + "/service/value1/" + value1 + "/value2/" + value2);

            int index = 0;
            for (InputStream image : images) {
                StreamDataBodyPart bodyPart = new StreamDataBodyPart("file" + index, image);
                multiPart.bodyPart(bodyPart);
                index++;
            }

            Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

            if (response.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is the server code that receives and processes the request:
@Path("service")
public class ServerController {
    
    @POST
    @Path("/value1/{value1}/value2/{value2}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getResponse(@PathParam("value1") int value1, @PathParam("value2") double value2, MultiPart multiPart) {
        List<InputStream> images = multiPart
            .getBodyParts()
            .stream()
            .map(bodyPart -> bodyPart.getEntityAs(InputStream.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        // Process images and generate response
    }
}

I have already registered the MultiPartFeature on the client side, but the server still responds with a 415 error. What could be the cause of this issue? How can I correctly send a list of images as a multipart POST request from the client to the server?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This looks like MultiPartFeature is not registered on the server side. It needs to be registered in Jersey 2.x and 3.0.x, it should not be required in 3.1.x.
